# How to create a composite component with dynamic attributes?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I have this composite component:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="image_1" />
    <cc:attribute name="image_2" />
    <cc:attribute name="image_3" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div id="slider-small">
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{cc.attrs.image_1}" />
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{cc.attrs.image_2}" />
            <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{cc.attrs.image_3}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

I use it in this way :

```
<cs:small_slider 
    image_1="about/1.jpg"
    image_2="about/2.jpg"
    image_3="about/3.jpg"
/>
```

but is limited to three attributes. What should I do if I have to send more than three, using the same composite component, like this:

```
<cs:small_slider 
    image_1="about/1.jpg"
    image_2="about/2.jpg"
    image_3="about/3.jpg"
    image_4="about/4.jpg"
    image_5="about/5.jpg"
/>
```

I want to do this to reuse the component and I don't want to create another.

**UPDATE**:
Follow @BalusC approach renders the follow HTML:

```
<!-- small slider --> 
<div id="slider-container"> 
    <div id="slider-small">
        <img src="/brainset/javax.faces.resource/1.jpg.xhtml?ln=images" />
        <img src="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
        <img src="RES_NOT_FOUND" /> 
    </div> 
    <div id="frame-slider-small"></div> 
</div><!-- end #slide-container -->
```

It not found the others images, only the first. I'm sure those images: 'about/2.jpg' and 'about/3.jpg' exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible and it also violates the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Your best bet is to *either* pass it as a `List<String>` from the bean instead so that you can iterate over it using `<ui:repeat>`:

```xml
<cs:small_slider images="#{bean.images}" />
```

with

```xml
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="images" type="java.util.List" required="true" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div id="slider-small">
            <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.images}" var="image">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{image}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </div>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

---

*Or* define it as a hardcoded comma-separated string instead and use JSTL [`fn:split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) to split them into a `String[]` which you in turn feed to `<ui:repeat>`:

```xml
<cs:small_slider images="about/1.jpg,about/2.jpg,about/3.jpg" />
```

with

```xml
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="images" type="java.lang.String" required="true" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div id="slider-small">
            <ui:repeat value="#{fn:split(cc.attrs.images, ',')}" var="image">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{image}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </div>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, try to be consistent with Java/JSF naming conventions. I'd rename your `small_slider.xhtml` to `renameSlider.xhtml` so that you can use it as `<cs:smallSlider>`, which is nicely in line with all normal JSF components.

Comment: i didn't know i could do that, thanks by the tips.
i update my post could you take a look, please ?

Comment: What approach did you take? The second? Did you put a space after the comma? If so, get rid of them.

Comment: You're welcome. You can alternatively also do `name="#{fn:trim(image)}"` so that you don't need to worry about those spaces.

Comment: is possible to have two variables in the same <ui:repeat> ?
Like, one value is the path to the image, just like we are doing and another is the title of the image.

Comment: Yes, if they have the same array index. You could then use something like `<ui:repeat value="#{array1}" varStatus="loop">#{array1[loop.index]}, #{array2[loop.index]}</ui:repeat>`.

Comment: i don't understand your last comment, i'm trying, but is not working.

Comment: This is actually offtopic. Feel free to ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the solutions BalusC mentioned  would be to (ab)use nested `f:param` tags. This would also allow to pass an additional parameter per image to the composite component. The name attribute in the following example is optional:

```
<cs:slider>
    <f:param name="image1" value="image1"/>
    <f:param name="image2" value="image2"/>
    <f:param name="image3" value="image3"/>
</cs:slider>
```

With the composite component defined like this:

```
<cc:interface>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div id="slider-container">
        <div id="slider-small">
            <c:forEach items="#{cc.children}" var="param">
                <h:graphicImage library="images" name="#{param.value}" title="#{param.name}"/>
            </c:forEach>
        </div>
    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Since your original problem was already solved, I'm writing this more to get some feedback on this approach.