# JSF2.0 composite add a rich tab for each of the values passed

Tags: java, jsf-2, composite-component

I'm using JSF 2.0 composite to have a kind of template and minimize my xhtml work for example I have this composite xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  >

<cc:interface>

    <cc:attribute name="tableHeadder" />
    <cc:attribute name="fechaValueInicial" />
    <cc:attribute name="fechaValueFinal" />
    <cc:attribute name="nombreSelectOne" />
    <cc:attribute name="valueSelectOne" />
<cc:attribute name="valueSelectList" />
    <cc:attribute name="nombreCommandButton" />
    <cc:attribute name="firstTabName" />
    <cc:attribute name="firstTabValue" />
    <cc:attribute name="secondTabName" />
    <cc:attribute name="secondTabValue" />
    <cc:attribute name="thirdTabName" />
    <cc:attribute name="thirdTabValue" />
    <cc:attribute name="funcionCommandButton" 
        method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />

</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

  <a4j:status onstart="#{rich:component('statPane')}.show()"
                onstop="#{rich:component('statPane')}.hide()" />

      <h:form>

        <rich:panel header="#{cc.attrs.tableHeadder}">
            <rich:messages/>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <h:outputText value="Del:"/>
                    <rich:calendar datePattern="dd/MMMM/yyyy" popup="true" mode="ajax"
                                   required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Selecciona una fecha inicial"
                                   locale="es" value="#{cc.attrs.fechaValueInicial}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Al:"/>
                    <rich:calendar datePattern="dd/MMMM/yyyy" popup="true" mode="ajax"
                                   required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Selecciona una fecha final"
                                   locale="es" value="#{cc.attrs.fechaValueFinal}" />

                    <br/><br/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.nombreSelectOne}" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{cc.attrs.valueSelectOne}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.valueSelectList}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <br/><br/>


                    <h:commandButton value="#{cc.attrs.nombreCommandButton}" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.funcionCommandButton}" />
                </div>


            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>

            <rich:tabPanel switchType="server">
                <rich:tab header="#{cc.attrs.firstTabName}">
                    <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.firstTabValue}" />
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab header="#{cc.attrs.secondTabName}">
                    <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.secondTabValue}" />
                </rich:tab>
                <rich:tab header="#{cc.attrs.thirdTabName}">
                    <ui:include src="#{cc.attrs.thirdTabValue}" />
                </rich:tab>

            </rich:tabPanel>

            <ui:include src="../../waitPopup.xhtml" />

        </rich:panel>
    </h:form>

</cc:implementation>
```

and implement it this way:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:CT="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/CompositeTemplates"
  >

<h:head>
    <title>Reporte de Recepcion de Leche</title>
</h:head>

<body>

    <CT:reportes
        tableHeadder="Reporte Recepcion de Leche"
        fechaValueInicial="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.fechaInicial}"
        fechaValueFinal="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.fechaFinal}"
        nombreSelectOne="Proveedores: "
        valueSelectOne="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.proveedor}"
        valueSelectList="#{CatalogoProveedoresLecheSI.selectList}"
        nombreCommandButton="Consultar"
        funcionCommandButton="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.consultar()}"
        firstTabName="Recepcion por Dia"
        firstTabValue="../../leche/lecheReporteProveedoresDia.xhtml"
        secondTabName="Recepcion por Mes"
        secondTabValue="../../leche/lecheReporteProveedoresMes.xhtml"
        thirdTabName="Recepcion por Proveedores"
        thirdTabValue="../../leche/lecheReporteProveedoresRecibido.xhtml"/>



</body>
```

I would like to, instead of declaring firstTab secondTab thirdTab, to just give for example 3 firstTab values and that composite creates 3 richTab components is this in any way possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one thing you could do is use  and create tabs dynamically.. a first approach (and you can improve this..) would be doing something like this..

in your component:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  >
<cc:interface>

    <cc:attribute name="tableHeadder" />
    <cc:attribute name="fechaValueInicial" />
    <cc:attribute name="fechaValueFinal" />
    <cc:attribute name="nombreSelectOne" />
    <cc:attribute name="valueSelectOne" />
<cc:attribute name="valueSelectList" />
    <cc:attribute name="nombreCommandButton" />

    <cc:attribute name="tabList" />

    <cc:attribute name="funcionCommandButton" 
        method-signature="java.lang.String action()" />

</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

  <a4j:status onstart="#{rich:component('statPane')}.show()"
                onstop="#{rich:component('statPane')}.hide()" />

      <h:form>

        <rich:panel header="#{cc.attrs.tableHeadder}">
            <rich:messages/>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <h:outputText value="Del:"/>
                    <rich:calendar datePattern="dd/MMMM/yyyy" popup="true" mode="ajax"
                                   required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Selecciona una fecha inicial"
                                   locale="es" value="#{cc.attrs.fechaValueInicial}" />
                    <h:outputText value="Al:"/>
                    <rich:calendar datePattern="dd/MMMM/yyyy" popup="true" mode="ajax"
                                   required="true"
                                   requiredMessage="Selecciona una fecha final"
                                   locale="es" value="#{cc.attrs.fechaValueFinal}" />

                    <br/><br/>

                    <h:outputLabel value="#{cc.attrs.nombreSelectOne}" />
                    <h:selectOneMenu
                        value="#{cc.attrs.valueSelectOne}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.valueSelectList}" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                    <br/><br/>


                    <h:commandButton value="#{cc.attrs.nombreCommandButton}" actionListener="#{cc.attrs.funcionCommandButton}" />
                </div>


            </div>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/>

            <rich:tabPanel switchType="server">
               <ui:repeat var="tab" value="#{cc.attrs.tabList}" >
                 <rich:tab header="#{tab.header}">
                    <ui:include src="#{tab.src}" />
                 </rich:tab>
               </ui:repeat>

            </rich:tabPanel>

            <ui:include src="../../waitPopup.xhtml" />

        </rich:panel>
    </h:form>

</cc:implementation>
```

now.. you should create a POJO to hold tab data:

public class TabData implements Serializable {

```
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


  private String header;
  private String src;

  public TabData(String header, String src) {
      this.header = header;
      this.src = src;
  }

  /* getters & setters */
```

}

in your bean.. just add a List and populate it ...

```
...

private List<TabData> tabs = new ArrayList<TabData>();

@PostConstrunct
public void init() {
   tabs.add(new TabData("Recepcion por Dia","../../leche/lecheReporteProveedoresDia.xhtml"));
   ...
}

/* Getter & Setter */
```

and finally..to use the component:

```
<CT:reportes
        tableHeadder="Reporte Recepcion de Leche"
        fechaValueInicial="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.fechaInicial}"
        fechaValueFinal="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.fechaFinal}"
        nombreSelectOne="Proveedores: "
        valueSelectOne="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.proveedor}"
        valueSelectList="#{CatalogoProveedoresLecheSI.selectList}"
        nombreCommandButton="Consultar"
        funcionCommandButton="#{lecheReporteProveedoresVB.consultar()}"
        tabList="#{bean.tabs}" />
```

I have never actually tried this approach with Richfaces, I have used it to create jQuery and it works fine....and again, you can improve on this..

Regards

Comment: looks perfect will implement tomorrow and give you feedback I was already thinking of something like this after all I saw a similar post using ui:repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902600/how-to-create-a-composite-component-with-dynamic-attributes?rq=1